# Query regarding checkboxes in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I found this code for select/unselect all checkboxes.  It works.  In each input has a name=list, I want that this code works with the `name=list[]`

When I change this option in the button in JavaScript appears error:

```
<input type=button value="Check All" onClick="this.value=check(this.form.list[])">
```

This is the original code:

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!-- Begin
var checkflag = "false";
function check(field) {
if (checkflag == "false") {
for (i = 0; i < field.length; i++) {
field[i].checked = true;}
checkflag = "true";
return "Uncheck All"; }
else {
for (i = 0; i < field.length; i++) {
field[i].checked = false; }
checkflag = "false";
return "Check All"; }
}
// End -->
</script>

<center>
<form name=myform action="" method=post>
<table>
<tr><td>
<b>Your Favorite Scripts & Languages</b><br>
<input type=checkbox name=list value="1">Java<br>
<input type=checkbox name=list value="2">JavaScript<br>
<input type=checkbox name=list value="3">ASP<br>
<input type=checkbox name=list value="4">HTML<br>
<input type=checkbox name=list value="5">SQL<br>
<br>
<input type=button value="Check All" onClick="this.value=check(this.form.list)">
</td></tr>
</table>
</form>
</center>
Read more about all by www.netevolution.co.uk
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type=button value="Check All" onClick="this.value=check(this.form['list[]'])">
```

Comment: Very well.  It's great.  Thanks.